# How do I conditionally align elements based on screen size?

Tags: html, css, header, css-float, nav

I have a fairly simple header on my site:

```
<header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="">
  <div class="navContainer">
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="leftNavSection">
        <img alt="My Logo" width="300" src="/assets/main_logo-791a416e4f99d38a339debb8dcebd7361d4172919425ace42ba2ce90336218e2.png">        
        </div>
        <div id="rightNavSection">
        Logged in as Dave A
        <a href="/users/edit">Edit</a>
        <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log Out</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    </header>
```

I align the logo to the left and the Logout links to the right:

```
#leftNavSection {
  float: left;
}

#rightNavSection {
  float: right;
}
```

What I would like, however, is if the screen size is small (mobile browsers), for the `Log Out` links to appear aligned to the left beneath the logo.

However, when I change the “float:right” to “float:left” this doesn’t happen.  Here is my Fiddle — https://jsfiddle.net/kje3q74k/.  How do I pull this off?

Comment: You should take a look into [CSS Media Queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile). That being said, try `float: none;` if you want the element to be pushed underneath instead of adjacently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's one way to do it:

1. Add `min-width: 50%` to the `leftNavSection` and `rightNavSection`.

> This allows the `rightNavSection` to wrap to the second line on
>   smaller displays when the content widths forces it down.

2. Remove the default margin of `body` using to adjust for the 100% width of the `navbar`:

   ```
   body {
     margin: 0;
   }
   ```

   Now the wrapping will occur exactly below 600px!
3. Float the `rightNavSection` to the left and align it to the right using `text-align: right`

   Below 600px use `text-align: left` using media query:

   ```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     #rightNavSection {
       text-align: left;
     }
   }
   ```

snippet below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
#leftNavSection {
  float: left;
  min-width: 50%;
}
#rightNavSection {
  float: left;
  min-width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #rightNavSection {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="">
    <div class="navContainer">
      <div id="navbar">
        <div id="leftNavSection">
          <img alt="My Logo" width="300" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        </div>
        <div id="rightNavSection">
          Logged in as Dave A
          <a href="/users/edit">Edit</a>
          <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log Out</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Hope you can take it forward from the above example. Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: I gave your suggestion a shot -- https://jsfiddle.net/kje3q74k/1/ , but the right section is not aligning completely to the right even though the screen is above 600 pixels wide.  I still want it to align all the way to the right if there is ample (> 600px) width.

Comment: you missed some styles for `rightNavSection` see this: https://jsfiddle.net/ks9z7waz/

Comment: Could you please upvote if this answer helped you? Thanks!